# I am getting an error in following folium code. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, data-science, folium

THIS IS MY FIRST ATTEMPT TO FOLIUM.
I have two columns in my data sets, 'states' and '%_criminals'. I want to plot those data on a choropleth map. I tried the following code. it's getting an error, which I don't understand.
Also, I want to know whats 'key_on' attribute used for.

name of data-set: Total_crime_rate
columns I want to use: ['state': name of states] & ['%_criminals': float values.]

```
india_map = folium.Map(location=[22.28,79.75],zoom_start = 5, tiles='Mapbox Bright')

!wget --quiet https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/cto2qv7nx6yq19logfcissyy4euo8lho.json -O world_countries.json

print('GeoJSON file downloaded!')

world_geo = r'world_countries.json'

threshold_scale = np.linspace(Total_crime_rate['%_criminals'].min(),
                              Total_crime_rate['%_criminals'].max(),
                              6, dtype=int)
threshold_scale = threshold_scale.tolist() # change the numpy array to a list
threshold_scale[-1] = threshold_scale[-1] + 1 

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=world_geo,
    data=Total_crime_rate,
    columns=['State', '%_criminals'],
    key_on='feature.properties.name',
    threshold_scale=threshold_scale,
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Crimes in INDIA',
    reset=True).add_to(india_map)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(india_map)
# display map
india_map
```

I am getting the following error. I tried to google it but could not find the solution.

`````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-0d755e6e2eec> in <module>()
      9     line_opacity=0.2,
     10     legend_name='Crimes in INDIA',
---> 11     reset=True).add_to(india_map)
     12 folium.LayerControl().add_to(india_map)
     13 # display map

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/features.py in __init__(self, geo_data, data, columns, key_on, bins, fill_color, nan_fill_color, fill_opacity, nan_fill_opacity, line_color, line_weight, line_opacity, name, legend_name, overlay, control, show, topojson, smooth_factor, highlight, **kwargs)
   1040                 style_function=style_function,
   1041                 smooth_factor=smooth_factor,
-> 1042                 highlight_function=highlight_function if highlight else None)
   1043 
   1044         self.add_child(self.geojson)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/folium/features.py in __init__(self, data, style_function, name, overlay, control, show, smooth_factor, highlight_function, tooltip)
    438             else:  # This is a filename
    439                 with open(data) as f:
--> 440                     self.data = json.loads(f.read())
    441         elif hasattr(data, '__geo_interface__'):
    442             self.embed = True

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:
    356         cls = JSONDecoder

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)````
`````

Comment: It looks like there's a problem with the JSON file.

Comment: @Barmar might be true. I am not a professional programmer but logically if there's a problem with JSON file, i should get an error on 'key_on ' line.!!

Comment: The error is happening while Folium is trying to load the file, nothing to do with the `key_on` line.

Comment: @Barmar okayy. i'll try with another link. Can you tell me what 'key_on' used for?

Comment: It's in the [documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html):  **Variable in the geo_data GeoJSON file to bind the data to.** There is no requirement to bind data (passing just a GeoJSON plots a single-color overlay), but there is a data binding option to map your columnar data to different feature objects with a color scale.

Comment: So `key_on=feature.properties.name` means that each name will be shown with a different color.

Comment: @Barmar I tried 3 different JSON files, I wrote that part of the code again, still, I am getting the same error.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I downloaded that URL and it looks fine.

Comment: I know it fine. Can't figure out the problem.@Barmar